Cannot bind my request object to Query params in Fastendpoints for GET request
I am using Fastendpoints to make my api but the issue I am getting is my request is not bounding to query params in GET request in Swagger. Here is my code.
Program.cs
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    var enumConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services
    .AddAuthenticationJwtBearer(s =>
    {
        s.SigningKey = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Secret"];
    },
    o =>
    {
        o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"];
        o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"];
    })
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddFastEndpoints()
    .AddSwaggerDocument(c =>
    {
        c.DocumentName = "v1";
        c.Title = "OctuFit API documentation";
        c.Version = "v1";
        c.Description = "OctuFit API documentation";

        // Enable JWT Bearer Authentication
        c.AddSecurity("JWT", new NSwag.OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = NSwag.OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = NSwag.OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
            Description = "Type 'Bearer {your JWT token}' to authenticate"
        });

        // Set Security Requirement
        c.OperationProcessors.Add(new NSwag.Generation.Processors.Security.AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT"));
    });
-----------------
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseDefaultExceptionHandler();

app.UseFastEndpoints(c =>
{
    c.Endpoints.RoutePrefix = "api";
});

app.UseSwaggerGen(uiConfig: c =>
{
    c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth = -1;
});

// Custom middlewares
app.UseMiddleware<PopulateUserDataMiddleware>();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<OctuFitContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();

    await Seeder.Seed(services);
}

app.Run();

My endpoint class is
public static class GetRolesEndpoint
{
    public class GetRolesRequest : PaginationRequestBase
    {

    }

    public class GetRoles : Endpoint<GetRolesRequest, PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<GetRolesResponse>>>
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private readonly IHasher hasher;
        private readonly RoleManager roleManager;

        public GetRoles(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            IHasher hasher,
            RoleManager roleManager)
        {
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            this.hasher = hasher;
            this.roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        public override void Configure()
        {
            Get("roles");
            Options(o => o.WithTags("Roles"));
        }

        public override async Task HandleAsync(GetRolesRequest req, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            var rolesQuery = roleManager.Roles
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(i => i.CreatedBy)
                .Include(i => i.UpdatedBy)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt)
                .Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(req.Search) || x.Name == null || x.Name.Contains(req.Search))
                .Where(x => x.TenantId == unitOfWork.TenantId)
                .AsQueryable();

            Response = new PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<GetRolesResponse>>
            {
                TotalRecords = await rolesQuery.CountAsync(),
                Data = await rolesQuery
                    .Skip((req.Page - 1) * req.PageSize)
                    .Take(req.PageSize)
                    .Select(role => new GetRolesResponse(
                        hasher.Hash(role.Id),
                        role.Name,
                        role.ToModifier()))
                    .ToListAsync()
            };
        }
    }

    public record GetRolesResponse(string Id, string? Name, Modifier Modifier);
}

And my base class is
public class PaginationRequestBase
{
    private int _page = 1;
    private int _pageSize = 10;

    [Required]
    [QueryParam]
    public int Page
    {
        get => _page;
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
            {
                _page = 1;
            }
            else if (value > int.MaxValue)
            {
                _page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                _page = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [QueryParam]
    public int PageSize
    {
        get => _pageSize;
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
            {
                _pageSize = 1;
            }
            else if (value > int.MaxValue)
            {
                _pageSize = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                _pageSize = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [QueryParam]
    public string? Search { get; set; }
}

The issue I am getting is, in Swagger, for GET request, I am getting the body instead of query params as shown:

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

you're using a wrong method to define a swagger document AddSwaggerDocument(). the correct method is SwaggerDocument().

Thank you so much. Everything is working fine now.
